# Is it possible to install themes without SSH, just by using FTP?

Tags: magento2, theme

I have a vps, installed Porto theme on Magento 2, I paid the theme developers for support.

Every time I face theme installation problem, or things like that, I contact the support.

They keep saying the same thing "Please give me FTP access and I'll check that for you."

I reply: "Are you sure you don't want SSH access?"

They don't reply, they don't seem to need it and they don't seem to know much about Linux either, I asked them to give me their public key so I can put it on the server, didn't reply and insisted on ftp access. Porto is the most popular and most well reviewed Magento theme of all time, and their support team is respected.

I'm just thinking about it, what can you do with FTP access? You cannot install a theme, you still need to run commands using ssh, you cannot even check to see if the file permissions are correct.

If given nothing but FTP access, is there anything you can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand you are worried about giving FTP access to someone on your server.

You can lock write access down a particular user and folder which would be your user.  But that said there is not a lot to stop them having a look around at other files. There are things you can do against this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83221/how-to-create-a-ftp-user-with-specific-dir-access-only-on-a-centos-linux-ins

Or is your question more on what you can do with only FTP?

In which case yes, you can check and update permissions using FTP.

Can't trigger trigger magento commands.  `php bin/setup:upgrade` etc.  You could however upload a script which does the same and trigger through browser.  A bit of a painful way to work though.

So what I generally say is that if you give out  SSH access they can use sFTP.  That's be best scenario.  But sounds like you already knew this.

Also quite easy to revoke user and/or ssh key.